# A racecar using amcl for navigation doesn't follow the path calculated by teb_local_planner as expected

Tags: ros, navigation, teb-local-planner

My racecar is controlled by ROS, and I am trying to make it work using AMCL for navigation. I set a goal to it. In the begining, it was working fine as expected, but soon it crashed into an obstacle because it didn't follow the path from teb_local_planner.

I tested this by making the car go through a U-shaped curve. Here are images of Rviz about the case. The green line is the global path and the orange one is the local path.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.